# How can I manually indent a paragraph inside an enumerate environment?

Tags: spacing, enumerate, indentation

I would like to manually insert an indentation on some lines inside an enumerate environment but not others. I am using the enumerate environment to number examples, but then inserting line breaks using `\\`. I would like to indent some of the paragraphs in examples like the following (but not all of them), so am trying to insert a space manually.

```
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label={(\arabic*)},resume]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\\
Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non.\\
Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id.
\end{enumerate}
```

However, `\indent` and `\hspace{\parindent}` are not working. What can I do to fix this?

---

EDIT:

The problem appears to go deeper than not being able to insert a `parindent`. I can't seem to insert any amount of `hspace` at the beginning of a line in the `enumerate` environment. Not even the following code produces the expected result:

```
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label={(\arabic*)},resume]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\\
\hspace{2em}Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non.\\
Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome! Let me rephrase your question. Do you want to indent **some** of the paragraphs inside `enumerate` and not all of them?

Comment: Yes. So I'm trying to manually insert an indentation, but I can't find a working solution.

Comment: Yes, I only want some paragraphs indented, not all of them. Judging by the question Kurt linked to, it seems that the problem might be that the enumerate environment sets `\parindent` to zero. I've tried working around this by defining `\newlength{\myenumindent}` and
`\setlength{\myenumindent}{\parindent}`, and then using `\hspace{\myenumindent}` where I want an indentation, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

Comment: While it's not the answer you really want, you *do* want to know that an ordinary `\hspace` will disappear at the beginning of a line.  However, `\hspace*` makes LaTeX pay attention so that the line will be indented.

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answer below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new length `\newlength{\enumerateparindent}`, then you can store the value of `\parindent` in it with `\setlength{\enumerateparindent}{\parindent}` outside of a list, because inside a list `\parindent` is set to zero. Therefore `\indent` is not working.

Now you can reuse it with your new length:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem} % <===============================================
\setlist[enumerate]{parsep=0pt}
\newlength{\enumerateparindent} % <=====================================

\begin{document}

\setlength{\enumerateparindent}{\parindent} % <=========================
\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\parindent}{\enumerateparindent} % <=========================
\item%
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

Version 2:
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label={(\arabic*)},resume]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\hspace{\enumerateparindent}Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non.

Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

In version 1 I showed the possibility to indent all new paragraphs. In version 2 I showed you how to indent only a special one.

Please see that you should not use `\\` outside a table. Also in `enumerate` use a blank line instead `\\`!

The result is:

[image]

Because you already use `enumitem` you can use a third version:

```
Version 3:
\begin{enumerate}[listparindent=\enumerateparindent] % <================
\item%
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{enumerate}
```

Here `listparindent` is set to `\enumerateparindent`. `listparindent` is taht value used for the indent with `enumitem`. Same result as my version 1.

The advantage with `\enumerateparindent` is that you always use the same length `\parindent` has ...

Comment: Thank you! The main problem appears to have been the use of `\\` to insert a line break. Your suggestion gives the result that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can play around with `enumitem`. The first `enumerate` lets no indentation for paragraphs. Whereas the next two modify the indentations for paragraphs. Remember you can link up `enumerate` environments with `[resume]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

     \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \lipsum[66]
        \lipsum[66]
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}[resume,listparindent=1.5em]
        \item
        \lipsum[66]
        \lipsum[66]
    \end{enumerate}


    \begin{enumerate}[resume,listparindent=1.5em, labelsep=2em, itemindent=1.5em]
        \item
        \lipsum[66]
        \lipsum[66]
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]